# My state is using it's initial values and not those that were set when the page loaded when called from a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Problem**

I have a "Calendar" component that when a day is click, it calls a function in it's parent (props). The whole day being clicked thing is not important as I've stripped a lot of the code to try to figure out where my issue is.

Within the parent, I have it run a function that console.logs a state. However, it uses the state's initial values and not the values that were set. Using a button I setup below the calendar (which calls the same function) results in the correct data however. Thus I know the data is being loaded and setted from my database.

**Expected Result**

Clicking a day on the calendar which calls a console.log function should display the state's values that were set when the page loaded.

**Actual Result**

The state that is console.log is using values from when it was initially created, not the values that were set.

**Things I've done**

Originally, the BookPage.js (the "parent" file) had a lot more code but I stripped it down until I found the issue had to do with the calendar component I made. To make sure that the issue wasn't related to my database, I added the Button below the calendar which called the same function as the calendar. Clicking the button results in the correct values being displayed.

---

**This is my page**

```
import { Colors, Styles } from "./GlobalStyles";
import {
  Button,
  Grid,
  TextField,
  Box,
  Tooltip,
  SvgIcon,
  Slider,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import {
  English,
  French,
  Spanish,
  Tagalog,
  Chinese,
  Korean,
  Arabic,
  Hindi,
} from "../Strings";
import moment from "moment";
import Calender from "./components/calender";

const BookPage = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    expert: null,
    availability: [
      [1, 24],
      [1, 24],
      [1, 24],
      [1, 24],
      [1, 24],
      [1, 24],
      [1, 24],
    ],
  };
  const reducer = (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState });
  const [state, setState] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    LoadExpertData();
  }, []);

  // Loads the expert's data
  const LoadExpertData = async () => {
    await props.firestore
      .collection("expertData")
      .where("userID", "==", props.bookID)
      .get()
      .then((loadedData) => {
        setState({
          availability: [
            [
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.sun[0],
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.sun[1],
            ],
            [
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.mon[0],
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.mon[1],
            ],
            [
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.tue[0],
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.tue[1],
            ],
            [
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.wed[0],
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.wed[1],
            ],
            [
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.thu[0],
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.thu[1],
            ],
            [
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.fri[0],
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.fri[1],
            ],
            [
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.sat[0],
              loadedData.docs[0].data().availability.availability.sat[1],
            ],
          ],
        });
      });
  };

  const alertData = () => {
    console.log(state.availability);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Calender language={props.language} ReturnDay={(d) => alertData()} />
      <Button onClick={() => alertData()}>BUTTON</Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookPage;
```

**This is the Calender**

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import { Colors, Styles } from "../GlobalStyles";
import {
  Button,
  Grid,
  TextField,
  Box,
  Tooltip,
  SvgIcon,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import moment from "moment";
import { English, French, Spanish } from "../../Strings";
const Calender = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    dateObject: moment(),
    weekdayshort: moment.weekdaysShort(),
    blankDays: [],
    yearLimit: [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023],
    month: 0,
    year: 2020,
  };

  const reducer = (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState });
  const [state, setState] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    GenerateCalender(null, null);
  }, []);

  // Finds the first day of the month
  const GenerateCalender = (m, y) => {
    if (m !== null && y !== null) {
      state.dateObject.month(m);
      state.dateObject.year(y);
    } else {
      setState({
        month: state.dateObject.month(),
        year: state.dateObject.year(),
      });
    }
    var firstDay = moment(state.dateObject).startOf("month").format("d");

    // Empty days
    var emptyDay = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < firstDay; i++) {
      emptyDay.push(<td style={LocalStyles.calSlot}>{""}</td>);
    }
    // Actual Days
    let actualDays = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= state.dateObject.daysInMonth(); i++) {
      actualDays.push(
        <td
          key={i}
          style={LocalStyles.clickableDay}
          onClick={() =>
            props.ReturnDay({
              month: state.dateObject.month(),
              day: i,
              year: state.dateObject.year(),
            })
          }
        >
          {i}
        </td>
      );
    }

    var days = [...emptyDay, ...actualDays];
    let rows = [];
    let cells = [];

    days.forEach((row, i) => {
      if (i % 7 !== 0) {
        cells.push(row);
      } else {
        rows.push(cells);
        cells = [];
        cells.push(row);
      }
      if (i === days.length - 1) {
        rows.push(cells);
      }
    });

    setState({
      calender: rows.map((d, i) => {
        return <tr>{d}</tr>;
      }),
    });
  };

  const ChangeYear = (year) => {
    GenerateCalender(state.month, year);
    setState({ year: year });
  };

  const ChangeMonth = (month) => {
    GenerateCalender(month, state.year);
    setState({ month: month });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        value={state.month}
        onChange={(e) => {
          ChangeMonth(e.target.value);
        }}
        style={{ width: 150 }}
      >
        {props.language.Calender.Months.map((m, v) => (
          <MenuItem value={v}>{m}</MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>

      <Select
        value={state.year}
        onChange={(e) => {
          ChangeYear(e.target.value);
        }}
        style={{ width: 150 }}
      >
        {state.yearLimit.map((y) => (
          <MenuItem value={y}>{y}</MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <p />
      {props.language.Calender.Months[state.dateObject.month()]}
      {state.dateObject.year()}
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td style={LocalStyles.calSlot}>
              {props.language.Calender.DaysShort[0]}
            </td>
            <td style={LocalStyles.calSlot}>
              {props.language.Calender.DaysShort[1]}
            </td>
            <td style={LocalStyles.calSlot}>
              {props.language.Calender.DaysShort[2]}
            </td>
            <td style={LocalStyles.calSlot}>
              {props.language.Calender.DaysShort[3]}
            </td>
            <td style={LocalStyles.calSlot}>
              {props.language.Calender.DaysShort[4]}
            </td>
            <td style={LocalStyles.calSlot}>
              {props.language.Calender.DaysShort[5]}
            </td>
            <td style={LocalStyles.calSlot}>
              {props.language.Calender.DaysShort[6]}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{state.calender}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

const LocalStyles = {
  calSlot: {
    width: 60,
    margin: 5,
  },
  clickableDay: {
    width: 60,
    margin: 5,
    cursor: "pointer",
  },
};

export default Calender;
```

Here, I have a screenshot of part of the page. I have the calendar and a button. On the right of the image is the result of both scenarios. The top is if a day on the calendar is clicked, it results in the state's initial values being used. The bottom is if the button is clicked, it results in the proper values that were loaded. Both call the same function that console.log the state.

[image: Image of the page and the results]

---

Comment: if you click the date in the calendar after those two clicks, what does it show?

Comment: I've stripped a lot of stuff out. Right now, clicking a day will call ""props.ReturnDay" with some data. The data doesn't matter as all I'm really doing is treating it just as a button. In the parent file, calendar's ReturnDay call will just run alertData() function which is the same function as the button is calling

Comment: is it re-rendering after your call to `setState`?

Comment: I'm assuming it is. To check, I put {state.availability[0][0]}{state.availability[0][1]} under the button and they are showing the correct values. Then clicking the calendar again I'm still getting incorrect values in my console while the numbers I just placed on the page are still showing the right values.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there is something fundamental I'm not understanding with the whole component lifecycle, but you could try [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback):

```
const alertData = React.useCallback(
  () => console.log(state.availability), 
  [state.availability]
);
```

Comment: The component does have a lot of fluff in it to calculate the actual calendar. At it's basis, its a table filled with <td>s that when clicked call the prop with the date clicked. In this stripped down version, the parent doesn't do anything with the date data and instead just calls a function to console.log some infomation. I tried making the change you suggested, but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: have you tried just `useState`? `const [availability, setAvailability] = React.useState([]);` You could then update the `useCallback()` to just be `availability` instead.

Comment: I tried that too and it still didn't fix it. I was still getting the same result

Comment: hmm unfortunately I'm out of ideas - sorry I couldn't help. Hopefully someone comes along. I attempted to reproduce extremely simply here https://codesandbox.io/s/still-lake-z7gg0?file=/src/App.js but was unable to. It seems to work as expected

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the calendar component. I'm just not sure where to start without gutting the whole thing